# Практика Codebra: перенос строки в HTML

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Всем привет, хотел бы задать вопрос новичка. Прохожу курс html на codebra, застрял на одном практическом задании. Нужно написать текст с переносом строк, так чтобы всё совпало с примером. Но как-то не выходит).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Задание:** 
*Оформите текст, как показано в "примере codebra". Желательно, используйте тег br.*

Код, который я пишу:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h4>Фраза</h4>
        <h4>Фраза</h4><br>
        <h4>Фраза Фраза</h4>
    </body>
</html>
```

И вот мой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добиться полного сходства?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
Фраза<br><br>
Фраза<br><br><br>
Фраза Фраза

<br><br>
-------------------
<br><br>

<p>Фраза</p>
<p>Фраза</p> <br>
<p>Фраза Фраза</p>
```

Comment: [![Принскрин задания](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4UR9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4UR9.png) У меня слова даже не двигаются при переключении, а все равно сходство только 26%